# Cassirer and the Categorical Imperative

Tags: reference-request, kant, continental-philosophy, categorical-imperative, cassirer

I've been reading some of the shorter works of the neo-Kantian and proto-semiologist Ernst Cassirer. While I find him a valuable bridge across the "continental divide," I'm not sure yet that I want to invest the time (and money) in his three-volume work on Theory of Symbolic Form.

But I'd be curious to know how Cassirer addresses Kantian morality and the categorical imperative. His work on science and math gives little clue, and from "Myth of the State," for example, I can't get a very clear idea of his political commitments, apart from his shocked anti-Fascism interpreted as a return of mythical structure.

His work is voluminous and not as well-referenced for students as many modern philosophers. Does anyone have an idea where, how, or if Cassirer writes directly on the moral legacy of Kant?

Comment: See [Aramayo, The Kantian Background to Cassirer’s Political Commitment](https://digital.csic.es/bitstream/10261/210581/1/kantian_background.pdf). There isn't much, his focus was on history, epistemology, and philosophy of science. The closest he comes to discussing Kantian ethics as such is in a little known study of Hägerström's philosophy.